# Unnecessary class vs Element selector (CSS performance)

Tags: html, css

Knowing that css is read from right to left, I'm wondering the performance/readability tradeoff between adding classes to the html just to target the elements in css more efficiently.

I'm also wondering how a generic element selector would affect performance with encapsulated components such as in Angular. For example, if I use a p selector in a component, when the page is compiled/rendered, will css search all p tags of the document or just the component?

```
<div>
  <span>hello world</span>
</div>

span {
  color: red;
}
```

vs

```
<div>
  <span class="text">hello world</span>
</div>

.text {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Performance is the worst metric to use when choosing your selector. While you might achieve a microscopic gain on a single rule, you'll likely end up creating more rules which will result in a greater total time, than if you chose your selectors based on matching the semantics of your document content.

Comment: ok that answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 span in your html file and your code forexample looks like it:

```
<div>
  <span>hello world</span>
  <span>Hello Again</span>
</div>
span {
  color: red;
}
```

And you are write to css this:

```
span {
  color: red;
}
```

in your website your span's is all of red so Hello world and the hello again.

BUT...

if you use this:

```
<div>
  <span class="text">hello world</span>
  <span>hello again</span>
</div>

.text {
  color: red;
}
```

in your website just hello world get colored by red...

Comment: Oh sorry... So yes the css file find all of "p" tag in html file